# Check field length

Tags: php, fields

I want to display one field, called {gearboxx_body}, unless that field has more then 300 characters, in which case I want to display a field called {article_blurb}. I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to do this just in EE fields and conditionals, so I tried some PHP, which I'm just starting to learn:

```
<?php 

  $info = array('{gearboxx_body}','{article_blurb}');

  if(mb_strlen($info[0]) <= 300) 
    echo($info[0]);
  }

  else {
   echo($info[1]);
  }

?>
```

So that works well, but there's a problem. If the tag includes any apostrophes or quote marks, it ends the string and the page won't load. So what can I do about this? I've tried to replace the quote marks in the string, but I have to have loaded the string from the fields first, and as soon as I do that the page is already broken.

Hopefully that made sense. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I should also mention that I **do not** want to install an external plugin.

Comment: I answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001342/importing-php-string-with-quotes/26001925#26001925

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't want to do this with a plugin but the fact is that it's the best way to do it. Not least because you can avoid the problem you have with Parse order.

The plugin needs a single line of PHP In the constructor, and returns a number;

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->EE =& get_instance();

    return strlen($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
}
```

That's it.

You can quickly get the framework for your own plugin from http://pkg.io

Then you can use it like so

```
{if "{exp:stringlength}{my-custom-field}{/exp:stringlength}" > 200}
    More than 200 characters
{if:else}
    Less than 200 characters
{/if}
```

Because you are effectively outputting the field contents to your template and **then** getting its length you avoid the problem of characters prematurely terminating the comparison.

** Update **
In a quiet moment I wrote a quick and dirty plugin to provide a wrapper around PHP's strlen() function which might prove useful in this case.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stringlength